# How to make my Android app update in time

Tags: android, database, sms, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Android app update in execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011482/how-to-make-android-app-update-in-execution-time)

Im trying something in android, that has to get the words sent in sms and print on the emulator screen. But the app doesnt update in time.

I send a message. Ok. But when I open the app it doesnt print the words that I've sent. So i have to close the emulator and then open it again, and run the app, and the word is there.

Id like that when I sent the message and then I access the app, the word is printed without I have to close the emulator.

How do I do this?

Thx.

---

So here is my code. Remember that I want to, send a new SMS and when I go to my app again, (without close and open the emulator), it updates the words in the screen, the new words shall be printed in the screen. Thx.

I have this class **SMS.java**, which is my activity, and another class, that is below this one here, called **DataHelper.java**, which manipulate my database, and has the methods to insert, query, update, etc.:

**SMS.java**

```
package com.sys;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import com.sys.DataHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.sys.ratedSmsContacts;
public class SMS extends Activity { 

private DataHelper dh;  
private static TextView txtView;                
private static Button btnChkCntts;
private static Button btnChkTag;

final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.dh = new DataHelper(this); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChkCntts);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ratedSmsContacts.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    });

    txtView =    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);      
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);                                    
        String body;  
        String atual;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            if(body == " "){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no words to save!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
                else{                               
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(body);                   
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                        atual = st.nextToken();
                            while(this.dh.select(atual) == true){
                                this.dh.atualiza(atual);
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Word updated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            while(this.dh.select(atual) == false){
                                this.dh.insert(atual);
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Word added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    List<String> words = this.dh.selectAll();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append("Set of words:\n\n");
                    for (String w : words) {
                        sb.append(w);
                        sb.append(" ");                         

                    }   
                    txtView.setText(sb.toString());
                }                   
        }             
   }
```

**DataHelper.java**

```
package com.sys;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sms.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "words";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
private SQLiteStatement updateStmt;
private static final String INSERT = "insert into " 
  + TABLE_NAME + "(word, cont) values (?, 1)";

public DataHelper(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
  OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
  this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();         
  //openHelper.onUpgrade(db, 1, 2);
  this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
 }

public long insert(String word) { 
  this.insertStmt.bindString(1, word);             
  return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
 }

public void atualiza(String word){
   this.db.execSQL("UPDATE words SET cont = cont + 1 WHERE (word= ?)", new String[] {word} );      
 }

public void deleteAll() {
  this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
 }

public boolean select(String wrd) {
  String word;
  Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"word"}, "word like ?", new String[] {wrd} , null, null, null);
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
        word = cursor.getString(0); 
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
  if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
     cursor.close();         
     return true;         
  }else{
      return false;
  }
}

public List<String> selectMaxCont(){       
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"word"}, null, null, null, null, "cont desc");
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
       do{
   list.add(cursor.getString(0));
       }while(cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
       cursor.close();
   }
   return list;
}

public List<String> selectAll() {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "word" }, null, null, null, null, "cont desc");
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0).toUpperCase()); 
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
         cursor.close();
      }
      return list;
   }

private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  OpenHelper(Context context) {
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT, cont INTEGER)");         
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     Log.w("SMS Words Database", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
     onCreate(db);
  }
 }
}
```